# How to test if a string character is a digit?

Tags: spss

How can I test if a certain character of a string variable is a digit in SPSS (and then apply some operations, depending on the result)?

So let's for example say, I have a variable that reflects the street number. Some street numbers have additional character at the end e.g. "12b". Now let's further assume that I extracted the last character (that could be a digit, or the additional letter) into a string variable. After that I'd like to check if this character is a digit or a letter. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this with the `MAX` function, where "mychar" is the character variable to be checked:

```
COMPUTE digitcheck = (MAX(mychar,"9")="9").
```

If the content of "mychar" is a digit [0-9] the result of the `MAX` function will be "9" otherwise the `MAX` function will return the letter and the equality test fails.

In this way you can also check if a whole string variable contains a letter or not. It looks pretty ugly though, because you have to compare every single character of your string variable.

```
compute justdigits = (MAX((CHAR.SUBSTR(mystr,1,1), CHAR.SUBSTR(mystr,2,1), CHAR.SUBSTR(mystr,3,1), ..., CHAR.SUBSTR(mystr,n,1),"9")="9").
```

Comment: might as well loop to `length(mystr)`

Answer (score 1):

If you try to turn a letter into a number then it becomes a missing value. Therefore, to test whether a character is a digit, you can do this:

```
if not missing(number(YourCharacter,f1)) .....
```

The same test can determine whether a string has only a number in it or not:

```
compute OnlyNumber=(not missing(number(YourString,f10))).
```

Note: using the `number` command on strings will produce warning messages which you can of course ignore.